# UISearchBar Disappears when tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` whose datasource and delegate is NOT handled by the view controller in which it is placed, but by another class called `AbstractInviteFriendsDataSourceDelegate`.

I have put a `UISearchBar` with `UISearchDisplayController` in the `UITableView` and manually (not using the storyboards interface) set their delegates and dataSources to the controller which handles the UITableView's dataSource and delegate.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        friendsArray = [FriendsToInvite new];
        UISearchBar *searchBar = [self.delegate theSearchBar];
        searchBar.delegate = self;
        UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplay = [self.delegate theSearchDisplayController];
        searchDisplay.delegate = self;
        searchDisplay.searchResultsDataSource = self;
        searchDisplay.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I think that this is ok, because when I implemented one of the search bar's delegate methods it got called correctly.

But now, when i tap on the search bar it slides to the left to make room for the cancel button and then it just disappears. I have not implemented any of the methods for the `UISearchBar` delegate, nor for the `UISearchDisplayController` delegate and dataSource.

I tried to implement `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` just to see if it gets called before the search bar disappears and yes, it's called but then after this method returns the search bar disappears.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I've fixed this problem, it seems that I had the `searchContentController` outlet from the storyboard. I set it back to the view controller that contains the table view and now it's ok.

Comment: Try to put constraints in your VC.

Comment: For some reason when I select the searchbar in the storyboard it doesn't allow me to put constraints, I can't select any of them.

Comment: I've just made sample project, put a UITableView and inside it I've placed UISearchDisplayController. Everything is ok. Please provide us with more feedback or upload your sample project so we can look at this problem.

Comment: Ok, I will now extend the question.

Comment: I've fixed this, check above.

Comment: It is very odd that you can't select you searchBar to implement constraint… Just put AutoLayout -> on. IMO constraints will fix this prob.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue and resolved by adding search bar in table view like this.

[image]